# How to 301 redirect WP posts id "/c/94940894" to permalink with post name?

Tags: redirect

My posts have  custom urls

```
https://demo.com/c/100038431
```

How can 301 redirect to

```
https://demo.com/post-name
```

Thanks ..

Comment: Is `100038431` in the example the post ID?

Comment: yes .. 
/c/100038431
As the site was converted from a special script to Wordpress, years ago